# Keyboard shortcut to go to beginning/end of current method

Tags: vim, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Coming from the Vim world, I very much miss the "[[" and "]]" commands that navigate to the beginning/end of the current method/procedure/subroutine. Trying to do this on sublime text and here's where I am:

1. A regex search of "^{" and "^}" does the trick as long as the code is Vim friendly.
2. Next step: replace this with a keyboard shortcut. I've gotten as far as:

   ```
   { "keys": ["alt+["], "command": "find_prev"},
   { "keys": ["alt+]"], "command": "find_next"}
   ```

So how do I pass (regex) args to this command?

Comment: `]] [[` in your vim goes to the beginning/end of method/procedure/function? are you sure about that? I press `]m ]M and [m [M` read `:h ]m and :h ]]` to learn the diff.

Comment: @Kent, I didn't know about ]m or ]M so thanks for that tip. They serve a different purpose though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
Ctrl+M
```

jumps to the ends of the current scope-block. So it will jump to the matching `{}` if your language uses those for code blocks. Pressing `Ctrl+M` subsequent times will alternate between ends of the code block. Additionally `Ctrl+Shift+M` will select the block.

Of course you can map this to a different keyboard shortcut if desired.

Comment: I am familiar with that. However, I need to traverse to the beginning/end of my function first to use `CTRL+M`. What I need a way to do that traversal quickly.

Comment: if you are in the middle of your function, `Ctrl+M` should jump to the end (or beginning I forget which...), multiple presses should get you to the other. Perhaps, however you don't want to duplicate keystokes... Just trying to think of something that already exists and could work for what you need to do.

Comment: Ctrl+M finds the _innermost_ matching brace. So if you are deep into several nested loops, you need to claw your way out one scope at a time. Unfortunately, that's the kind of code I am dealing with :)

Comment: fair enough, then my answer is not what you are looking for.